# Pre-Populate a WTforms in flask, with data from a SQLAlchemy object

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am fairly new to flask framework and was creating an edit profile page for a webportal. I am stuck at a point and am unable to autofill a form.

Here is my form class :

```
class EditProfile(Form):

    username = TextField('Username', [Required()])
    email = TextField('Email', [Required()])
    about = TextAreaField('About', [Required()])
    website = TextField('Website', [Required()])
```

This is my function that evaluates the form.

```
def editprofile(nickname = None):
    if g.fas_user['username'] == nickname  or request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfile()
        form_action = url_for('profile.editprofile')
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
            if form.username.data == nickname : 
              query = EditProfile(form.username.data,
                                 form.email.data,
                                 form.about.data,
                                 form.website.data,
                                 )
              print query #debug
              db.session.add(query)
              db.session.commit()
              flash('User Updated')
              print "added"
            return(url_for('profile.editprofile'))
        return render_template('profile/add.html', form=form,
                               form_action=form_action, title="Update Profile")
    else:
        return "Unauthorised"
```

And my html template for form is form is :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title %}
        {{ title }}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <div id="Edit Profile">
        <h2>{{  title  }}</h2>
        <form method="post" action="{{ form_action }}">
            <fieldset>
                <legend></legend>
                {{ render_field(form.username) }}
                {{ render_field(form.email)}}
                {{ render_field(form.about )}}
                {{ render_field(form.website) }}
            </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

I have an object, of user class. And from that object I want to prefill this form.How can I prepopulate the values in the form. I am trying to implement the edit profile functionality here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to pass your object to the form when you create it.

```
form = EditProfile(obj=user)  # or whatever your object is called
```

You're going to run into some trouble with

```
          query = EditProfile(form.username.data,
                             form.email.data,
                             form.about.data,
                             form.website.data,
                             )
          db.session.add(query)
```

It creates a new instance of your `EditProfile` form. You then try to add it to the session. The session wants models, not forms.

Instead, after validating the form, you can associate its values with the object.

```
form.populate_obj(user)  # or whatever your object is called
```

Because your object was already loaded, you won't need to add it to the session. You can remove `db.session.add(query)` and just call `db.session.commit()`.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. Once I am sending my user object in the form i need to edit the template also i think, otherwise how will the it associate the correct correct feild with models ? As data members in my user model and form class are having different names.

Comment: Why are they different? Also, can you show us the model?

Comment: https://github.com/hammadhaleem/fedora-college/blob/develop/fedora_college/core/models.py

Here are my models.

Comment: Based on your `EditProfile` form above and your code on GitHub, the fields have the same names in your user model and form.

Comment: Yeah, I have chnaged the names, and it works now. But What can be done to keep their names different.

Comment: You still haven't said *why* you want them to be different. It's a common practice for form fields to match the names of the model fields they represent.

Comment: @dim what if I don't need to populate all the data from the form, populate_obj will try to mass assign all form fields but I only want to mass assge some of the form

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way I've found of doing this is to fill the form fields on a get request.

```
@decorator_authorized_user  # This decorator should make sure the user is authorized, like @login_required from flask-login
def editprofile(nickname = None):
    # Prepare the form and user
    form = EditProfile()
    form_action = url_for('profile.editprofile')
    my_user = Users.get(...)  # get your user object or whatever you need
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = my_user.username
        form.email.data = my_user.email
        # and on
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # This section needs to be reworked.
        # You'll want to take the user object and set the appropriate attributes
        # to the appropriate values from the form.
        if form.username.data == nickname: 
            query = EditProfile(form.username.data,
                                form.email.data,
                                form.about.data,
                                form.website.data,
                                )
            print query #debug
            db.session.add(query)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('User Updated')
            print "added"
            return(url_for('profile.editprofile'))
    return render_template('profile/add.html', form=form,
                           form_action=form_action, title="Update Profile")
```

This sets up the function to return a prefilled form on a get request. You'll have to rework the section under `form.validate_on_submit`. Dirn's answer suggests a few of the right things to do.

Answer (score 13):

To populate the form with your SQLAlchemy object use:

```
form = EditProfile(obj=<SQLAlchemy_object>)
```

If your form fields don't match the database columns in your model for whatever reason (they should), the form class takes kwargs:

> **kwargs – If neither formdata or obj contains a value for a field, the form will assign the value of a matching keyword argument to the
>   field, if provided.

I found that one use case for this is if you have a form that contains fields that reference more than one model (e.g. through a relationship); passing the one `obj` isn't enough.

So let's take your example and say that in your database model (for `user`) you use `site` instead of `website` (the form field name). You'd do this to populate your form from the SQLAlchemy object:

```
form = EditProfile(obj=user, website=user.site)
```

Then in the POST you'd have to do this to populate your SQLAchemy object from your form:

```
form.populate_obj(user)
user.site = form.website.data
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: how can i repopulate MultiSelectField ? i don't mean to use obj, i want to use the field name but it doesn't work for me

Comment: I don't know why this example was so hard to find now in 2020 :^( Here is a page at PalletsProject about [Select, Insert, Delete](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries). Almost all the CRUD, but what about Update--SQLA obj into a WTForms object? %^\