# Python Flask: Respond to forms

Tags: python, forms, flask

Using `Python 2.7` and `Flask` how do I automatically respond to forms? I'm new to using Flask. Specifically, I'd like to render a basic calender on a Flask server and once a date/week is selected print this in the console.

The screen shot below shows I can see this form with the server running and to illustrate I've only included a calender and text input field. On selecting a date/week nothing happens - I only see the dictionary output (highlighted in the red rectangle, bottom image) once I type and **press enter** within the text field. After which the data is printed in the console and cleared from the form; I'd like the data to remain once entered too.

Screen shot and code shown:

[image]

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print request.form
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

and form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/", method="post">
            Date:<br>
            <input type="week" name="date" step="1" min="2015-W30" value="2015-W9">
            <br>Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to maintain the data after doing a submit? You could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712986/pre-populate-a-wtforms-in-flask-with-data-from-a-sqlalchemy-object).

Comment: "What do you mean by remain?"  - Just that, to remain within the form after submission. "What do you mean by nothing happens?" - the form is not submitted on a calender date being selected - that's the purpose of my question. "Do you want to submit data without pressing enter (doing a submit?)" - Yes, this is what I meant in the original post, i.e.  the submission process is enacted by the user selecting a calender date, not by pressing any submit buttons or pressing enter. Does that make sense?