# How to pass Flask-SQLAlchemy base query class to Flask-wtforms

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have been refactoring some code to use SQLALchemy but have been using Flask framework so have been using the extension Flask-SQLAlchemy.

I run a query on my model that has two inner join and where clauses on it. This can be seen below;

```
    rows = Master.query.join(
    Company,
    Master.company == Company.company_id
).join(
    Countries,
    Master.country_id == Countries.country_id
).filter(
        ((Master.relevant == 1) | (Master.relevant == 0)),
        ((Master.displayed == 0) | (Master.displayed == 1)),
    Master.sent == 0,
    Master.date >= '2017-12-31 23:59:59'
).with_entities(
    Master.id,
    Countries.country_name,
    Company.company_name,
    Master.date,
    Master.info,
    Master.link
).order_by(Master.date.desc())
```

However as I want to populate `flask-wtforms` I have created the form class;

```
class BusinessOps(FlaskForm):
    id = TextField('id', [Required()])
    company = TextField('company', [Required()])
    country = TextField('country', [Required()])
    date = TextField('date', [Required()])
    info = TextField('info', [Required()])
    link = TextField('link', [Required()])
```

then in my view I have the following;

```
@app.route('/business-ops', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def buisness_opportunities():

rows = Master.query.join(
    Company,
    Master.company == Company.company_id
).join(
    Countries,
    Master.country_id == Countries.country_id
).filter(
        ((Master.relevant == 1) | (Master.relevant == 0)),
        ((Master.displayed == 0) | (Master.displayed == 1)),
    Master.sent == 0,
    Master.date >= '2017-12-31 23:59:59'
).with_entities(
    Master.id,
    Countries.country_name,
    Company.company_name,
    Master.date,
    Master.info,
    Master.link,
    # Master.relevant,
    # Master.displayed,
    # Master.sent

).order_by(Master.date.desc())

print(type(rows))

form = BusinessOps(obj=rows)

print(form.data) #returns dict with null values for keys

return render_template('business-ops.html', form=form)
```

Originally when I run this code together, I received no output, so I tested by printing `form.data` and saw it returned me an empty value dictionary. So I then printed the `type` of `rows` and it returned me `<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'>`.

After reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712986/pre-populate-a-wtforms-in-flask-with-data-from-a-sqlalchemy-object) I understood that I would be able to pre-populate the data in my form from the data in the query?

Comment: `form = BusinessOps(obj=rows.first())` might do the trick. I'm pretty sure you need to pass the object not just the query to the form. Though I've never actually tried to populate directly from a query.

Comment: Ok makes sense, but I need to pass all the data, I have just read about [field enclosures](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.2/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList) this seems more like what I am trying to achieve, will give it a go

Comment: With your current form you can really only display the data for 1 object. If you need help with field enclosures, SelectQueryFields, etc.., I would ask that explicitly in a different question.