# Return elements in SQLAlchemy AppenderBaseQuery object to Flask-WTForm field

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am working on the "edit" functionality for a form. When the form is rendered, the fields should populate with data that is stored in the database. One of this field is returned as a SQlAlchemy AppenderBaseQuery object. This causes a query statement to be pre-populated in the field, instead of the results of the query.

How do I pre-populate the form with elements in the object instead?

```
form = MyForm(obj=MyObject)

if form.validate_on_submit():
    form.populate_obj(MyObject)
```

The field is defined as a StringField.

**Note**:
I am passing MyObject to pre-populate the form because there is a thing with WTForm where `form.Field.data` does not get updated at all.

```
form = MyForm()
form.Field.data = "test" #Pre-populate Field with "test"

if validate_on_submit():
    MyObject.Field = Form.Field.data #Assign data in Field to MyObject
    #...
```

My Object.Field will not be updated with the new `Form.Field.data`, not sure why.

Comment: In the second example, are you committing the session to the database?  If not, that could be a reason why MyObject.Field isn't seeming to get updated.

Comment: Yes it's committed to db. There's another question that outlines the issue with Flask_WTForms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712986/pre-populate-a-wtforms-in-flask-with-data-from-a-sqlalchemy-object

Comment: Was going to write out a suggestion, but it's pretty much there in Eric Workman's response to the post you linked.  let `if form.validate_on_submit` deal with `POST` requests and have a separate branch along the lines of `elif flask.request.method =="GET"` to deal with filling the form.

Comment: Works! Have provided an answer below for future reference. Seems like a common problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by n-Holmes in the comments:

```
# Do not initiate the form with object
form = MyForm() 

# Split logic to 'GET' and 'POST request'
if request.method == 'GET'
    MyForm.Field.Data = ', '.join([element.attribute for element in MyForm.Field.all()]

    # MyForm.Field is an AppenderBaseQuery Object >> Returns a query statement
    # MyForm.Field.all() returns a list of Objects
    # The list comprehension returns a list of a specific attribute for each object
    # The .join combines the list to a string, separated by ", "
    # This entire thing is pre-populated onto the form
    # Eg: "Attribute01, Attribute02, Attribute03"

if validate_on_submit:
    MyObject.Field = FunctionToUpdateField(form.Field.data)

    # form.Field.data will be a string
    # FunctionToUpdateField compares above string with what is stored in db ...
    # determines which elements to add / remove
```